# Does Turf.js work with geodjango?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geodjango, django, turf

I am trying to do a simple buffer around a geojson I created with a model.  The buffer does not show up.  Here is my code.

```
    lyrStores2 = L.geoJSON.ajax("{% url 'stores' %}", {

    }).addTo(mymap2);
    storeBuffer = turf.buffer(lyrStores2.toGeoJSON(), 10, {units: 'miles'});
    lyrStoreBuffer = L.geoJSON(storeBuffer, {style:{
            color:'green',
        }
    }).addTo(mymap2);
```

The layer itself appears just fine.  I'm not sure if the geoJSON isn't appearing because I havn't created a url or a view for it like I had to for the shapefiles I created models for...

I have tried linking the  for the minified js and even tried this cdn

src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"

Update:
So I saved the file as a geoJson using qgis.  I put the file into my static folder and everything worked fine.  This is what the code looks like for that:

```
    Storesjson = L.geoJSON.ajax("{% static 'mymap/data/storesgeojson.geojson' %}");
            Storesjson.addTo(mymap);

    Storesjson.on('data:loaded', function(){
            jsonStores = turf.buffer(Storesjson.toGeoJSON(), 10, {units: 'miles'});
            storesBuffer = L.geoJSON(jsonStores, {
                    style: {
                        color: 'red',
                    }
                }).addTo(mymap);
            });
```

The original file is loaded in like this

```
lyrStores = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'stores' %}", {

            });
```

My url for that looks like

```
path('Store_data/', Stores_datasets, name='stores'),
```

This is my view where I have it serialized:

```
def Stores_datasets(request):
stores = serialize('geojson', Stores.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(stores, content_type='json')
```

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console in your browser for errors?

Comment: Yes, there is no error.  It has to do something with the way i'm loading it in.  I put a geoJson (the same file just saved as a geoJson while before it had to be serialized through django into a geoJson) in the static folder and turf worked just fine.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, have you figured this out?

Comment: question answered -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627582/turf-js-buffer-executing-but-geojson-not-being-added-to-leaflet-map

Comment: @ziggy oh man thanks for the update.  I actually ended up using an API and Angular on the front end.

Comment: I think I've the same problem with MapBox here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58771147/it-cant-possible-to-render-a-buffer-using-turf